# Flink 1.10 on yarn consume kafka 0.9 failed

Tags: apache-flink, kafka-consumer-api

I want to submit job in flink on yarn mode, just consume records and print.Codes run good on my local computer, but failed when submit to yarn.I've tried to change dependency or put jar into lib dir, but it didn't work.Any idea about this? Thanks a lot.

Codes and environment is below.

flink 1.10, kafka 0.9.

code:

```
        FlinkKafkaConsumer09<String> kafkaSource = new FlinkKafkaConsumer09(
                "test",
                new SimpleStringSchema(),
                properties);

        kafkaSource.setStartFromLatest();
        DataStream<String> stream = env.addSource(kafkaSource);
        stream.print().setParallelism(1);
```

part of pom

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka-0.9_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

error info

```
2020-05-14 20:22:22,925 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Source: 

Custom Source -> Sink: Print to Std. Out (1/1) (dd3a239f2854c735c23ab307ff277e62) switched from RUNNING to FAILED.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internal.KafkaConsumerThread.<init>(Lorg/slf4j/Logger;Lorg/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/internal/Handover;Ljava/util/Properties;Lorg/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/internals/ClosableBlockingQueue;Lorg/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/internal/KafkaConsumerCallBridge09;Ljava/lang/String;JZLorg/apache/flink/metrics/MetricGroup;Lorg/apache/flink/metrics/MetricGroup;Lorg/apache/flink/api/common/io/ratelimiting/FlinkConnectorRateLimiter;)V
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internal.Kafka09Fetcher.<init>(Kafka09Fetcher.java:113)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer09.createFetcher(FlinkKafkaConsumer09.java:270)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.run(FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.java:695)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:100)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:63)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask$LegacySourceFunctionThread.run(SourceStreamTask.java:196)
```

Comment: solved, lib dir has flink-sql-connector-kafka_2.11-1.10.0.jar, KafkaConsumerThread both appear in flink-sql-connector-kafka_2.11-1.10.0.jar and flink-connector-kafka-0.9_2.11-1.10.0.jar, use different class of metric: org.apache.kafka.common.Metric 
 vs org.apache.flink.kafka.shaded.org.apache.kafka.common.Metric

Comment: Add, explain and accept your answer.